# Why the Type property is written in *.resx file

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

Sometimes in *.resx files for Forms I see records like this:

```
<data name="&gt;&gt;labelControl1.Type" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl, DevExpress.XtraEditors.v15.1, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789abc123</value>
</data>
```

The DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl doesn't have a Type property (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsLabelControlMembersTopicAll)

Why the WindowsForms Designer write this to resources? Type can not be different in different languages, isn't it?

Comment: You also don't have a variable named `>>labelControl1`.  You are just seeing extra context info being added to get the job done.  Some fake names you may encounter are [listed here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/Resources/ResXResourceWriter.cs,e68101a2263ac695).